# How can I sort IP addresses in MySql, so ipv4 comes before ipv6 addresses?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, ip-address

I have a table in MySQL with a column containing ip addresses - stored as 'VARCHAR(40)'. Both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses are used.

Now I want to sort those addresses, but I want all ipv4 addresses to come before all ipv6 addresses.
I have tried:

`ORDER BY INET6_ATON(IpAddress)` where `IpAddress` is the name of the column. `INET6_ATON` returns a 'VARBINARY(16)'.

Sorting on that will give a result like this:

```
35.229.251.134
2405:204:900e:e66c::1441:48a1
37.9.113.28
```

where ipv4 and ipv6 are mixed. This is of course because 24 (hex) is 36 (decimal), which comes between 35 and 37.

How can I sort the ip addresses, so ipv4 always come before ipv6?

**Edit:**

I'm considering change the column to 'VARBINARY(16)' using '`INET6_ATON`' to store the values. Does that give more possibilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with. First I did:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(INET6_ATON(ipAddress)) ASC, INET6_ATON(ipAddress) ASC
```

That works, but is of course not very effective.

Then I (finally) converted the column to `varbinary(16)`, using `INET6_ATON` when saving (or .Net's `IPAddress.GetAddressBytes()` when using a DataTable).

Now I can simply do:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(ipAddress) ASC, ipAddress ASC
```

which is very effective. I now get all ipv4 addresses to appear before all ipv6 addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the `.` and put them first:

```
order by (ipaddress not like '%:%') desc,  -- ipv4 desc
         INET6_ATON(IpAddress)
```

Comment: Won't that put '::ffff:255.255.255.255' before everything?

Comment: @PoulBak . . . There are no examples like that in the question.  And that is something of an edge case.  But I changed the answer to look for a colon rather than periods.